# Imperative of "distrarre"

Tags: verbs

The imperative of "distrarre" is "distrai!". This is like "fare", whose imperative is "fa'" or "fai". With an object particle it becomes "fallo". Does that happen with "distrarre" (and "trarre") as well? Because "distrallo" and "trallo" sound terrible to me, but a friend of mine is convinced they're right. I would say "distràilo" and "tràilo". Which is right?

Comment: There is a joke on this theme for when you want to correct someone speaking bad Italian: "Ma almeno l'italiano sallo!" (instead of "sappilo").

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*(dis)tràilo* and *tràilo* are **correct**.

(About the mere words and their existence in Italian it comes to my mind only *strallo*: a steel cable for buildings or in boats)

But why in *tràilo* the "i" pre-clitic is preserved while in *dallo* and *fallo* is "lost"?

Probably because *dare* and *fare* (together with *dire*, *stare*, *andare*) don't follow the "usual" pattern of conjugation and have an apocopated/shortened form.

Source:

http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/imperativo_%28Enciclopedia_dell%27Italiano%29/

Comment: Thanks for the Traccani link: so, *fa'*-like forms predate *fai*-like ones! (Probably coming from the irregular Latin imperative forms *dic*, *fac* etc.)

Comment: @DaG That's the same I knew: the two forms *fa'* and *fai* developed independently. The apostrophe is just an orthographic device, not really related to truncation/elision.

Comment: @metafora I was talking about the specific case, where the apostrophe *doesn't* denote the elision *fai* > *fa'*, as the latter form predates the former.

Answer (score 5):

I'm a native Italian speaker and I agree with you, I say "Distràilo" and not "Distrallo" which is incorrect. Same goes for the verb "Trarre", "Trailo" is the correct form while "Trallo" is incorrect.

Comment: Indeed. *Fallo* derives from the *fa'* form; since *distra'* does not exist, *distrallo* has no reason to exist either.

Comment: Yes, Correct @DaG

Comment: Never use very common verbs as a template to infer the rules for the other verbs. :-) Words that are used a lot become worn out and develop exceptional behaviours.

Answer (score 1):

This phenomenon is known as **[univerbation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Univerbation)** with **[syntactic gemination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_gemination)** (or *syntactic doubling* [[raddoppiamento sintattico](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/raddoppiamento-sintattico_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/) in Italian]) that occurs when [clitics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clitic) ([*clitici*](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/clitici_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)) in italian) are welded with *strong **monosyllabic** verbal forms* (typically the second person singular of the imperative).

We have:

- fare: *imp.* fai, fa' → fa'+lo=fa**ll**o, fa'+ti=fa**tt**i
- dire: *imp.* di'→ di'+lo=di**ll**o, di'+ci=di**cc**i
- dare: *imp.* dai, da'→ da'+lo=da**ll**o, da+mi=di**mm**i
- andare: *imp.* vai, va'→ va'+ci=va**cc**i
- stare: *imp.* stai, sta'+ci=sta**cc**i
- etc.

*The second person singular, thanks to his affective content (volitive), is inclined to shorten* (see Rohlfs, Historische Grammatik der italienischen Sprache und ihrer Mundarten, Vol. 1, §606).

See for example:

- tenere: *imp.* tieni, tieni+lo=tienilo but we have
  ***Tienlo*** a mente, e legatelo al dito., 
  *E **tienlo** un poco in collo, almen tanto, che pianga la madre.* 
  (cfr. colloquial forms te’ ‹tè› or tie’ ‹ti̯è›)
- venire: *imp.* vieni, vieni+ci=vienici but we have
  *Siam derelitti pargoli. Deh! **vienci** a benedir.*

With the verbs **trarre** and its compounds (*contrarre, distrarre, attrarre, etc.*) **we don't have vowel apocope** or *shortening of the regular form* in the imperative and we have ***univerbation*** only:

- trarre: *imp.* trai → trai+lo=trailo
- distrarre: *imp.* distrai → distrai+lo=distrailo
- attrarre: *imp.* attrai → attrai+le=distraile

Comment: Do you know if there is a linguistic explanation on why vowel elision does not happen on trarre?

Comment: *(dis)trai* follows the rule, *fa', da', di', etc.'  are exceptions (some of them coming from latin fac, dic)

Comment: @alexjo They're not “exceptions”. As already told in a comment to the accepted answer, *fa', da', di', va', sta'* predate *fai, dai, dici, vai, stai* and are *not* elisions thereof.

Comment: @egreg Actually it's [apocope](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/apocope/). In this sense an "exeption"

Comment: @alexjo No, in those case it isn't *apocope*, or whatever you want to call it: the forms with the apostrophe *predate* the longer ones, so they cannot be their truncations, elisions, *apocope* or whatever.

Comment: @egreg  Not in opinion of [treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/troncamento_(La-grammatica-italiana)/) (at the end of the post)

Comment: @alexjo Yes, in the opinion of [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/imperativo_%28Enciclopedia_dell%27Italiano%29/). The link you show *doesn't* actually say they're truncations and is about a different topic anyhow.

Comment: @egreg So, [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/fa-o-fa-fa_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/) also has contrasting opinions. ..

Comment: @alexjo I beg to disagree; the link you cite is about orthography, not linguistics. The “short” forms *appear* like truncations of the “long” ones, although they linguistically aren't.

Comment: @egreg I'm sorry too, but the post [troncamento](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/troncamento_(La-grammatica-italiana)/) is about linguistics and not just orthography...but different opinions are common in the field of linguistics...

Comment: @egreg Also [here](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-si-dice/E/elisione-troncamento.shtml) they have a different opinion...